# Accept Credit Cards without Businness Account

Tags: paypal

**Problem:**
I have a personal project and I want to be able to accept donations from users in a kiosk-like fashion using an Android tablet as the display/interface and a credit card reader. I was planning on using the REST API, however, this project is not associated with any business so I can't get a business PayPal developer account to enable accepting payments directly from credit cards.

**Questions:**
Is it possible to accept credit cards directly without a business account, or create a business account for an individual/personal? Would it be possible for me to get the credit card information and amount first, then pass that information to the PayPal UI to streamline the process so the user only has to tap a confirmation button?

**Details:**
My ideal user story:

1. User swipes card through card reader
2. User enters amount to donate
3. User confirms donation and is done

Simple and easy.

I realize that I can use a PayPal donate button but that is a much more complex user story and, as far as I know, without hacking the UI it will not be possible to support swiping the card and the user will have to enter the card information manually. Using the mobile SDK it might be possible to support card swiping but I still do not like the added layers of the PayPal log-in screen, having to select "Pay as guest", entering the amount in the textbox, etc. It needs to be an extremely simple process as I outlined above.

**Possible (bad) Solution:**
My last hope would be to collect the information, then in the background invisible to the user a web view would automate the donation process through PayPal by programmaticly going through the pages and filling out the textboxes. The web view would then be shown to the user once the final confirmation page is displayed for the user to tap the confirmation button. This is extremely hacky and a bad solution, however.

**Side Question:**
Why can I accept credit card payments through the PayPal UI (via a guest PayPal "account") without a business account, but I can't use the API to do so?

**Unimportant Details:**
I am building a KegBot which is a "smart" kegerator that tracks beer consumption and other data. The Android tablet displays this information and other fun stuff. I have a donation jar to help pay for the kegs but a common problem (or excuse) is that people don't have cash and only have plastic. My plan is to connect a card reader to the tablet as an accessory (or maybe use PayPal's card reader) to give drinkers a way to easily swipe a card and donate.

I am considering simplifying down the user story even more and making it so when the user swipes their card it automatically donates $5 without any other interaction needed. Maybe a confirmation button.

Comment: Hey Mike, are you familiar with PayPal Here? Sounds like you'd be trying to create exactly that functionality: (US) https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader / (UK) https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader

Comment: I am, but this does not help me at all. The PayPal Here app does not work in a kiosk (self serving) environment and is even further from my desired user experience. But it does raise the question again: Why can I accept credit cards through this app but not through the REST API?

Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried going through the application to register my developer account as a business account and the form had changed. I was able to select Individual as the business type and use my home address and phone number. The application was approved and I now have a business account capable of processing credit cards using the rest API.